# Global section $s$ of ample line bundle such that $X_s$ is everywhere dense

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective $k$-scheme of pure dimension $n$ where $k$ is a field. Let $L$ be 
an ample line bundle on $X$. For all $x \in X$ there is some open neighborhood $U 
\subseteq X$ and an isomorphism $w: L_{\mid U} \cong \mathcal{O}_U$.

> Show that there is some $n \geq 1$ and a global section $s 
> \in L^{\otimes n}(X)$ such that
>   $$
>  X_s = \{ x \in X \mid w_x(s_x) \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\times  \}
> $$
>   is everywhere dense, i.e. $s$ does not vanish identically on any of the irreducible 
>   components of $X$.

**EDIT:**

I want to emphasize that I am interested in an answer that will also work over a finite field $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that some power of $L$ is very ample, i.e. you find a closed immersion $i: X \to \mathbb P^n_k$ with $i^*\mathcal O(1) = L^n$.

Now for each irreducible component $V_i$, pick a point $p_i \in V_i$. Certainly there is a global section of $\mathcal O(1)$ which does not vanish at all $i(p_i)$ (A hyperplane can always avoid finitely many points). Its pull-back to $X$ is a section of $L^n$ which does not vanish at all $p_i$.

Comment: Do you need $k$ to be infinite?

Comment: This is a very mild hypothesis in such a geometric context.

Comment: Also the assertion should be wrong for $\mathcal O (1)$ on  the projective line over a finite field, since its topology is discrete.

Comment: @MooS What I originally want to show with the above assertion is only a real task if the ground field $k$ is finite. But the assertion above is also true for $X$ irreducible since for some power the considered line bundle is globally generated and thus there need to be a global section not vanishing at the whole space.

Thus I want to find an answer which also works over finite fields.

Comment: @MooS In your original comment to my answer, you wrote something like that the ampleness of the pullback of $L$ to a irreducible component gives a section not vanishing there. What did you have in mind to make that section of the pullback of $L$ to a global section of $L$?

Comment: You should try to figure out that this also works for finite fields. I think it does.

Comment: @MooS and with **this** you mean the approach in your answer?